# AWS cannot delete RestApi

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-rest-api

On deleting AWS Rest API from UI or through AWS console or terminal with command:

```
aws apigateway delete-rest-api --rest-api-id 1234123412
```

(mentioned in aws docs)
I faced the error saying to delete base-path mappings related to RestApi in your domain,
I tried deleting it with the following cmd given in aws docs:

```
aws apigateway delete-base-path-mapping --domain-name 'api.domain.tld' --base-path 'dev'
```

I got error: An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling DeleteBasePathMapping operation. Invalid base path mapping identifier specified

Answer (score 24):

Delete the corresponding domain name from the UI (under 'Custom domain names').

After which, the RestApi can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
aws apigateway delete-base-path-mapping --domain-name domain.tld --base-path "(none)"
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/delete-base-path-mapping.html